# ¿Cómo puedo comprimir todas las tablas de una vez?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Mi base de datos tiene 250 tablas y debo pasar de compact a compress, quisiera ejecutar el comando de una vez para todas las tablas.
Con este comando se hace de una en una:

```
ALTER TABLE  `nombre_de_la_tabla` ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED ;
```

Comment: Eso es más facil hacerlo en un script... estás en Windows o en Linux?

Comment: Desde MySQL Workbench, con la consola de Scripting puedes acceder fácilmente a todas las tablas y sus propiedades, desde ahí igual puedes modificarlo con un pequeño script, yo lo hice para pasar los nombres de todas las tablas a minúsculas.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera 'quick and dirty': armate el mismo script en mysql:

```
 SELECT CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE `',
               table_name,  
     '` ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED ;') 
 FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE 
 ROW_FORMAT <> 'Compressed' AND
 TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```

Corre esto desde mysql y redirige la salida a un archivo `out.sql`, o bien
copia lo anterior a un archivo `in.sql` y corre

```
 mysql -N -u MI_BASE_DE_DATOS -p MI_BASE_DE_DATOS < in.sql > out.sql
```

Revisa que el archivo `out.sql` se vea correcto, y luego correlo

```
   mysql -u MI_BASE_DE_DATOS -p MI_BASE_DE_DATOS < out.sql
```

(En ambos caso, reemplaza  MI_BASE_DE_DATOS  y MI_BASE_DE_DATOS por tus datos - y omite `-p` si no usas password)

Answer (score 0):

No se si exista un metodo para hacerlo con todas las tablas, pero se me ocurrre que realices un procedimiento almacenado, el cual deberia funcionar de la siguiente manera:

1 crear un cursor que recorra todas las tablas 
puedes usar la consulta

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

2. por cada tabla ejecutar tu instrucción

```
ALTER TABLE  `nombre_de_la_tabla` ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED ;
```

En teoria ese algoritmo debería hacerte el proceso mas facil.